# How to distinguish preprocessor and compiler directives?

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-construction, c-preprocessor, openmp

I have been told that `#pragma omp` directive in GCC is directive of the compiler, and is not directive of the preprocessor.

Is it correct?

How to distinguish preprocessor's and compiler's directives?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a quote from [gcc docs](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Pragmas.html)

> This manual documents the pragmas which are meaningful to the preprocessor itself. Other pragmas are meaningful to the C or C++ compilers. They are documented in the GCC manual.

Acccording to that, there are preprocessor pragmas and non-preprocessor pragmas.

> How to distinguish preprocessor's and compiler's directives?

Preprocessor directives are specified in the C standard, compiler directives are described in the compiler manual.

About your edit, the linked page does not mention `#pragma omp` and if you combine that with the quote above, I would reason that the pragma is not for the preprocessor. It is definitely compiler specific.

Answer (score 5):

`gcc -E` runs the preprocessor only. So inspect the output of that: anything left in there is for the attention of the compiler proper.

With some experience of C++ you won't need to do this every time because you'll learn what the preprocessor does and what the compiler does. Some of the things controlled by `#pragma` cannot conceivably be done by the preprocessor, so it follows that it must be a compiler directive in those cases (or in theory it could be replaced with an equivalent compiler directive by the preprocessor -- if you care about the difference then again, `gcc -E` will show what happens). However, some of the things `#pragma` does relate to preprocessing (`#pragma once`), and so it must be a preprocessor directive in those cases.

Your example `#pragma omp` is a compiler directive by both tests. By general knowledge, the preprocessor isn't anything like smart enough to parallelize code. It doesn't even understand most of the C++ code it sees, basically all it can do is integer arithmetic with constants, macro replacement, and shovelling text around. For a direct test with `gcc -E` try the following file:

```
#if 1
    #pragma omp
#endif
```

output is some filename/line-number annotations plus:

```
#pragma omp
```

So we observe that `#if` and `#endif` have been handled by the preprocessor, while `#pragma omp` has not.

Comment: I specified the question. The sentence was about pragma omp.

Comment: @klm123 you _edited_ the question to add omp... his answer was made before your edit. It's not right to criticize him for that... at the time he answered, you did **not** have a sentence about pragma omp.

Comment: @mah, do I criticise? I inform.

Comment: @mah: if my answer is quite wrong, please do criticise it :-). But I didn't take klm123's comment above as a criticism, just as a request to consider also the specific case of `#pragma omp`. The question remains how to distinguish *in general*. I don't feel that providing a motivating example changes that other than that an answer should consider that example.

Comment: @SteveJessop your answer is not wrong -- I had that leftover in a cut-and-paste from the deleted message... sorry!

Comment: @klm123 your method of informing, in this case, makes it look like SteveJessop wasn't paying attention to the question when he answered. In fact, you weren't paying attention to it when you posted (just as I wasn't paying attention to my comment enough to edit it before posting)... you (and I) only made that observation after posting so we own the mistakes. I feel a better "inform" from you would have been "I've made a change to my post to include....".